# .htaccess execution order in subdirectories (wordpress/laravel)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

Good morning Stack! My website is currently structured like this:

1. http://www.mywordpressite.com/
2. http://www.mywordpressite.com/.htaccess
3. http://www.mywordpressite.com/portal/
4. http://www.mywordpressite.com/portal/.htaccess

My understand of the universe is that if I navigate to portal, (4)'s .htaccess will parsed instead of (or with preference over) (2)'s .htaccess. In reality, I am observing that even while navigating to (3) http://www.mywordpressite.com/portal/, the .htaccess from (2) is taking over.

As you can imagine, the root directory is a wordpress site with a standard wordpress .htaccess file:

/.htaccess

```
<files wp-config.php>
Order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The portal is a Laravel portal, with a standard Laravel .htaccess file

/portal/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I've noticed is that if I remove (2) /.htaccess, all of a sudden, everything works with the portal, so there is certainly collision occurring. I won't post my vhost stuff here since both .htaccess's work / do what they are supposed to do -- just not at the same time:

/.htaccess redirects pretty much pipes all input where the input doesn't correspond to a file or directory into the index.php file for better parsing.

/portal/.htaccess does something similar.

What I've noticed is that with both .htaccesses, if I navigate to a route that usually would be parsed by the portal's .htaccess, such as http://www.mywordpressite.com/portal/this/is/a/route I end up getting a 404 from my *wordpress* site (eg it piped the url into the /index.php file of the wordpress root directory), and of course that page doesn't exist in WP.

When I remove the wp /.htaccess, of course wordpress doesn't work right anymore, but all of a sudden, the portal's .htaccess starts working fine and http://www.mywordpressite.com/portal/this/is/a/route fires the appropriate route by piping the url parameters into /portal/index.php for processing.

This seems backwards to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried excluding `/portal` form the WP rule-set, like this:`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/portal  [NC]` below `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`, and adding `/portal` to the portal rule set, like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/portal  [NC]`? You have to add `RewriteBase /portal` to the portal rule-set anyway, as MikeAnthony says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you've left out a `RewriteBase` in the portals access file:

```
RewriteBase /portal/
```

I'm not a hypertext access genius, so I can't explain what happens when you leave it out. But I'm sure that's the solution.